# jQuery filter according to checkbox status

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm using jQuery "filterable" plugin to filter data, this plugin originally filters data by clicking on category's name link, now I'd like to change link to check box, so if checkbox is checked that certain category shows and if it gets unchecked, it goes hidden.
here is the jquery:

```
(function(jQuery) {
    jQuery.fn.filterable = function(settings) {
        settings = jQuery.extend({
            useHash: true,
            animationSpeed: 1000,
            show: { width: 'show', height: 'show', opacity: 'show' },
            hide: { width: 'hide', height: 'hide', opacity: 'hide' },
            useTags: true,
            tagSelector: '#portfolio-filter input[type=checkbox]',
            selectedTagClass: 'current',
            allTag: 'all'
        }, settings);

        return jQuery(this).each(function(){

            /* FILTER: select a tag and filter */
            jQuery(this).bind("filter", function( e, tagToShow ){
                if(settings.useTags){
                    jQuery(settings.tagSelector).removeClass(settings.selectedTagClass);
                    jQuery(settings.tagSelector + '[value=' + tagToShow + ']').addClass(settings.selectedTagClass);
                }
                jQuery(this).trigger("filterportfolio", [ tagToShow.substr(1) ]);
            });

            /* FILTERPORTFOLIO: pass in a class to show, all others will be hidden */
            jQuery(this).bind("filterportfolio", function( e, classToShow ){
                if(classToShow == settings.allTag){
                    jQuery(this).trigger("show");
                }else{
                    jQuery(this).trigger("show", [ '.' + classToShow ] );
                    jQuery(this).trigger("hide", [ ':not(.' + classToShow + ')' ] );
                }
                if(settings.useHash){

                    location.hash = '#' + classToShow;
                }
            });

            /* SHOW: show a single class*/
            jQuery(this).bind("show", function( e, selectorToShow ){
                jQuery(this).children(selectorToShow).animate(settings.show, settings.animationSpeed);
            });

            /* SHOW: hide a single class*/
            jQuery(this).bind("hide", function( e, selectorToHide ){
                jQuery(this).children(selectorToHide).animate(settings.hide, settings.animationSpeed);  
            });

            /* ============ Check URL Hash ====================*/
            if(settings.useHash){
                if(location.hash != '')
                    jQuery(this).trigger("filter", [ location.hash ]);
                else
                    jQuery(this).trigger("filter", [ '#' + settings.allTag ]);
            }

            /* ============ Setup Tags ====================*/
            if(settings.useTags){
                jQuery(settings.tagSelector).click(function(){
                    jQuery('#portfolio-list').trigger("filter", [ jQuery(this).attr('value') ]);

                    jQuery(settings.tagSelector).removeClass('current');
                    jQuery(this).addClass('current');
                });
            }
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

I'm using "hash" method so it adds something like "#categoryname" at the end of page url when the relative checkbox is checked,and then it shows some items related to that check box,now I want to hide those item when the checkbox is unchecked and also remove that hash.